# Javascript - clearInterval

Tags: javascript, animation

Can anybody help me with clearInterval? I have been working with it for hours and can't seem to get it to work. I am using a very similar code to what I found on W3 schools as follows:

Here is also a link to see in action: http://hyque.com/ani/drawImageBtn.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DrawImage with Buttons</title>
</head>

<body>

<button id="startBtn">Start</button>
<button id="stopBtn">Stop</button><br />

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="125" height="187" style="border:1px solid       #d3d3d3;">

<script>


window.onload = function() {
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://hyque.com/ani/adam.png";  
var xPos = 0;

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 120, 182, 0, 0, 120, 182);

var el = document.getElementById('startBtn');
el.addEventListener('click', strt, false);

var el2 = document.getElementById('stopBtn');
el2.addEventListener('click', stopIt, false);

function imageXPosition() {


ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 120, 182);  // This clears the canvas

ctx.drawImage(img, xPos, 0, 120, 182, 0, 0, 120, 182); //Draws the  individual frames


xPos += 120; //adds the width

//This adds 1 to the second frame
if(xPos == 120){
    xPos += 1;
} 
if(xPos > 841){xPos = 0;}   // This resets to 0 after the las frame


}
function strt(){
var intStp = setInterval(imageXPosition, 200);

}
function stopIt(){
    clearInterval(intStp);
}   
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var intStp` is local scoped only inside `strt()`. You can't access it outside that function

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at scoping:

```
 var intStp;
 function strt(){ 
 intStp = setInterval(imageXPosition, 200); 
} 
function stopIt(){ 
clearInterval(intStp);
 }
```

A variable inside of a function only exists until the function ended, unless it isnt bound to inner functions (see Closure).

```
function(){
var a;//a is declared
 }
 //a is deleted
```

And functions cannot access other functions properties, unless it is accessing a variable of an outer function.

You may read on MDN : JS Scoping, Functions, Variables (mainly : the basics)

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. I was wondering if it was a scope problem. I guess It's all part of the learning process.

Comment: Concerning learning progress: please mark it as answer ;) ( to tell other helpers, that youre already satisfied...)

Answer (score -1):

IntStp variable in local scope start function. Just omit the var keyword

Comment: This is a bad practice. Should always declare variables within their appropriate scope